# how to make registry changed values to take effect without signing out?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, batch-file, windows-registry

If I manually change registry key values using cmd. they failed to take effect/changes until I restart/sign-out my computer.

Eg.

```
reg ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v MouseWheelRouting /t REG_DWORD /d 2 /f
```

i have to restart/sign-out to them the changes to take effect

but I wanna find a way to make them work without having them to restart/sign-out my computer.

So, Is there simple possible way to this to happen? using batch/cmd.

Comment: I was wondering if after you set the registry key if running from command line `WMIC PROCESS WHERE "Caption = 'explorer.exe'" CALL TERMINATE`—not sure if elevated as administrator makes any difference or not either so consider testing with and without run as administrator—if that makes the changes effective without having to restart/sign-out. If so, please tag me back and I'll be happy to write up an answer with more detail if you want. Should be simple enough to test regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can get these new settings to take effect if you broadcast the `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message.

In AutoIt, for example, you could do something like

```
#include <SendMessage.au3>
Dim Const $WM_SETTINGCHANGE = 0x001A
Local $hWnd = WinGetHandle("[CLASS:Shell_TrayWnd]")

If @error Then
    MsgBox(0, "", "An error occurred when trying to retrieve the window handle.")
    Exit
Else
    _SendMessage ($hWnd, $WM_SETTINGCHANGE)
EndIf
```

Comment: thx, but is there any simpler way using cmd only ?